# Problems starting VMware Workstation 11 on Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrade from 14.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, vmware, vmware-workstation

I just upgraded a 14.04 machine to 16.04 (64bit - Gnome-Shell).

The upgrade worked without obvious issues. After finishing the upgrade and rebooting the machine i am not longer able to start VMware Workstation 11.1.3 (which worked on this machine before with 14.04).

Clicking the VMware Workstation launcher/icon in `plank` (yet another dock) results a short visible vmware entry in the Gnome panel which then disappears.

Starting `vmware` from terminal gives no output and the workstation GUI doesn't appear. The terminal returns to the prompt without output.

I was wondering if i should try to reinstall workstation but decided to ask first

Any help is appreciated

**Update**

1. Uninstall & reinstalling vmware workstation had no effect
2. Starting vmware from terminal via

   env VMWARE_USE_SHIPPED_LIBS=1 /usr/bin/vmware

Results at least in some output and reaches the moment where it wants to compile its modules & load into the kernel.

This ends with an error

```
 Loop on signal 11
```

This happens for my main user and as well if i start vmware with sudo privileges.

Content of `/var/log/vmware/hostd.log` can be seen [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16373080/).

Comment: Have you tried to re-install Workstation?  Before doing that make backups of your virtual machines.

Comment: Yes - did that - without effect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After doing a big amount of tests including uninstall & reinstall ,removing preferences and rebuilding modules i found the following solution.

**Temporary**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**Permanent**

```
echo /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1 | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/LD_LIBRARY_PATH.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

As a result i am again able to start vmware by

```
vmware
```

**UPDATE:**

Please see the answer of @Michael Firth as it might be a better/cleaner approach.

Answer (score 6):

As a variation on dufte's answer, I was able to get it working again by adding the

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Line into `/usr/bin/vmware` and `/usr/bin/vmware-netcfg`, which are both actually shell scripts.

I was nervous of the other option, as it changes the library behaviour for all things on the system, rather than just VMware

Comment: Yes, very good idea to consider that and to find an elegant solution. +1