# Problems remain starting VMware Workstation 11 on Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrade from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, vmware

A similar problem was noted at [Problems starting VMware Workstation 11 on Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrade from 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770801/problems-starting-vmware-workstation-11-on-ubuntu-16-04-after-upgrade-from-14-04).  Briefly, VMware Workstation 11 does not launch after an Ubuntu upgrade.  Uninstalling and re-installing has no effect.

The post suggested two solutions, one "temporary" and the other "permanent."

The remaining problems, obviously profound, are:
(a) In neither case will VMware launch upon clicking the icon, as was the case before the Ubuntu upgrade.
(b) Neither solution persists after closing the terminal shell.  Instead, one must look up the code the poster cites, re-enter it in the terminal, and then launch VMware from the terminal.

Any thoughts for getting VMware to install and run on Ubuntu 16.04 other than by kludge would be most gratefully received.

I should note that Ubuntu 16.04 is not a supported host operating system for VMware Workstation 11, according to the VMware online documentation.  So, this may be more than a minor bug, and a kludge or VMware upgrade (to Workstation 12) may be all that's available.

Comment: Why does the permanent solution not work? It writes to a file so it should survive both a closed/re-opened terminal and even a reboot or shutdown. Can you confirm that the data is in fact written to the file in question `cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/LD_LIBRARY_PATH.conf`. Actually should LD_LIBRARY_PATH be $LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Having a quick read through this [http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setting-changing-library-path/](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setting-changing-library-path/) seems to indicate that `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/LD_LIBRARY_PATH.conf` should probably be `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/vmware.conf`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/770801/problems-starting-vmware-workstation-11-on-ubuntu-16-04-after-upgrade-from-14-04