# Problems starting VMWorkstation 11.1.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vmware-workstation

Fresh install Ubuntu 16.04, Linux 4.15.0-38-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, and VMware Workstation 11.1.4. VMware workstation will not start. Already uninstalled/reinstalled but no luck. Found the following post [Problems starting VMware Workstation 11 on Ubuntu 16.04 after upgrade from 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770801/problems-starting-vmware-workstation-11-on-ubuntu-16-04-after-upgrade-from-14-04) but OS was upgraded and different kernel version.

Fails compiling Virtual Machine Monitor and Virtual Network Device.
[VMware Kernel Module Updater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU2cA.png)

2018-10-25T16:04:57.945-04:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2018-10-25T16:04:57.946-04:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.15.0-38-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2018-10-25T16:04:57.946-04:00| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2018-10-25T16:04:57.949-04:00| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2018-10-25T16:04:57.949-04:00| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j12 -C /tmp/modconfig-nDiJoK/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.15.0-38-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-10-25T16:04:59.529-04:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.